# finding file system path for VNode

Tags: macos, mono, pinvoke

I need to use [vn_getpath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Kernel/Reference/vnode_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011950) function (defined in vnode.h as part of Kernel framework) in Mono-based project, so I'm going to use PInvoke for importing it. But I can't figure out which library should be referenced in DllImport attribute. I have tried 'LibC' and '/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Kernel', but no luck so far.

**Does anyone know which library the function is located in?**

*My ultimate goal:*
I'm collecting details for ALL processes running in a system. I use [sysctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/10.6/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html) to enumerate processes. From sysctl call I can get process ID and VNode of process's executable. Now I need to get file system path to process's executable.
I'm looking at vn_getpath and [fcntl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/10.6/man2/fcntl.2.html) (with F_GETPATH command).
On vn_getpath, I can't figure out which library I can import it from, using DllImport attribute.
As to fcntl, I have found it in the LibC, but the function requires file descriptor (instead of vnode).

**In general, I need any idea on how to get file system path from vnode, with any number of intermediate steps.**

TIA
Ivan

Comment: I have found the solution, but it is based on PID rather than VNode. There is proc_pidpath function (http://astojanov.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/mac-os-x-resolve-absolute-path-using-process-pid) that does the trick, and it works for all processes whether it is system or user one. It should be noted that Process Manager API (http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ProcessManager) works for user processes only.

Answer (score 0):

The `vn_getpath` function is not defined in a library, it's part of the kernel and can only be used in the kernel and kernel extensions:

```
$ otool -tv /mach_kernel  | grep vn_getpath
_vn_getpath:
_vn_getpath_fsenter:
```